# Format credit card numbers as four digit blocks in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have this credit card number in a Google Sheets of the following format:

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

How can I make it display like `XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX` or `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` where they're in four digit blocks?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the cell as _Plain text_ and then editing the number to display in the credit card format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With dashes (`-`):

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,4)&"-"&MID(A1,9,4)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))`

or with spaces ():

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4)&" "&MID(A1,5,4)&" "&MID(A1,9,4)&" "&RIGHT(A1,4))`

Comment: I can't make a comment for some reason (I guess my rep is too low), but it's worth noting that @Raystafarian's answer (currently top rated) can cause serious harm if the spreadsheet is ever analyzed without the formatting (i.e. parsed by an application) as it will hide input mistakes. Example: Input: `1000100010001000` Output: `1000-1000-1000-1000` Input: `10001000100010001000` Output: `1000 1000 1000 1000`

Comment: @Koviko I know I'm *about* 3 years late here, but in this case, the formula output is most likely in a different column than the raw data and any application (etc) would most likely use the raw data column, as it may (or may not) just print the formula if using the display column. Your disclaimer is valid if not using the raw data column, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simpler with a Custom Number format of:

```
#### #### #### ####
```

Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number format ...

Comment: it doesn't work, last number is converted to 0 sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(text("1234567890123456", "####,####"), ",", "-")

=REGEXREPLACE(text("1234567890123456", "####,####"), ",", " ")
```

### OUTPUT:

1st: `1234-5678-9012-3456`

2nd: `1234 5678 9012 3456`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Google Sheets follows the IEEE 754 specification for how to store and calculate floating-point numbers. It therefore stores only 15 significant digits in a number and changes digits after the fifteenth place to zeros.
You would need to change the format to text.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. How this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

I use customer number format, "#### #### #### ####", it almost works perfect except a very annoying issue, it keep convert last digit to "0". don't know why.